# Why do I have no power in my bedroom but other circuits on that breaker do?

Tags: electrical

In my room the ceiling fan stops and there's no light and no power in wall socket. I plug the TV, phone and DirecTV to an extension cord running to the bathtub socket which is on a breaker by itself. My roommate is the only one that does it. It pops on and off. All other bedrooms are on the same breaker but still have power.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you saying your _room_ is the only room in which it happens, or are you saying your _roommate_ is causing it? This is a typo that can change the whole context of the question...

Answer (score 1):

Either there's a switch somewhere that controls power to your room (bad switch on the power strip?), or the power strip you're using has a self-resetting thermal breaker (unlikely)... or you've got a wiring problem. I'd recommnd determining which ASAP.